# Insert a google tag manager variable into a URL within custom tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have a URL like the following for a marketing pixel in Google Tag Manager. This is in a custom JS tag which is an img src pixel.

"https://report.myurl.com/cgi-bin/a.gif?event=event-name&user={{User Id}}"

What is the recommended method for including the variable in a URL string?

Comment: Have you tried exactly what you've done in your example? That is, define the `{{User ID}}` parameter and just use it as is. I presume you've got the User ID in the dataLayer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that User ID is declared within GTM and is defined, before the tag is triggered and naming convention is exactly the same, rest looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have seen now that GTM actually recognises an image pixel when you mistakenly copy it into custom JS :| and puts it into the correct format/tag. Tag is triggered and firing with this format now.